# how to send an email via sendgrid API V3 using templates, full example

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

I'm reading through the [send grid documentation about templates here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Transactional_Templates/index.html) and could find this:

> You can send transactional templates using one of three ways:
>
> 1. Using the SMTP Relay
> 2. Including the template ID in the templates
>      parameter of the Web API v3 Mail Send endpoint
> 3. Using the x-smtp api parameter in the Web API v2 Mail Send endpoint

In node.js I have access to their [JS SDK](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs). However, In API the documentation it is explained only how to use the first method (SMTP relay). In the documentation of the JS SDK there is no option for sending emails using a template.

Where can I find a complete example of how to use the JS SDK of send grid to send an email using a template?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an example buried in an issue on the Github repository: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/252#issuecomment-232473145

```
var sg = require('sendgrid').SendGrid("SendGrid API Key" or <environment variable>)

function sendEmail(tempID){
    var helper = require('sendgrid').mail;
    from_email = new helper.Email("frome-mail@example.com")
    to_email = new helper.Email("to-email@example.com")
    subject = "Dummy Subject"
    content = new helper.Content("text/html", "dummy content")
    mail = new helper.Mail(from_email, subject, to_email, content)

    substitution = new helper.Substitution("-name-", "User's Name")
    mail.personalizations[0].addSubstitution(substitution)
    mail.setTemplateId(tempID)
    var requestBody = mail.toJSON()
    var requestPost = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(sg.emptyRequest()))
    requestPost.method = 'POST'
    requestPost.path = '/v3/mail/send'
    requestPost.body = requestBody
    sg.API(requestPost, function (response) {
       console.log(response.statusCode)
       console.log(response.body)
       console.log(response.headers)
  })
}
```

In my case, it worked fine. I get the email but response is always empty.